# How to define type of json in header of in xml file

Tags: json, laravel

How can I define data type in this code.I am facing error define data type.Can any body suggest me this answer

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://test-cwc.house.gov/offices",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I am facing this error.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

echo json_encode($response)

**Try it I hope you get your answer from it

`header('Content-Type: application/json')`

`echo json_encode($response)`

**

Comment: welcome dude, I ma here you can again use this platform in any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your CORS use

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the

```
$middleware property of app/Http/Kernel.php class:
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

Now update the config to define the paths you want to run the CORS service on, (see Configuration below):

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],
```

The defaults are set in config/cors.php. Publish the config to copy the file to your own config:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

On Lumen, just register the ServiceProvider manually in your bootstrap/app.php file:

```
$app->register(Fruitcake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider::class);
```

Also copy the cors.php config file to config/cors.php and put it into action:

```
$app->configure('cors');
```